# Do people actually make / invent anything?

Tags: discussion

I am looking for suggestions on how to reword this question to better fit the site and narrow the scope to a specific doctrine question.

[Do people actually make / invent anything?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/25477/do-people-actually-make-invent-anything?noredirect=1#comment61117_25477)

Comment: It seems to be more philosophical than doctrinal if that makes sense. That's the reason I closed it.

Comment: I understand your reasoning - and agree.  I am asking for suggestions - if there can be any - to get it back on track.

Comment: I recommend reading some of scientist, theologian, and philosopher, John Polkinghorne's work.  In particular, a lecture entitled ["God's Action in the World"](http://www.starcourse.org/jcp/action.html), will give you a taste.  I don't know how to ask your question, but doing some research into the problem is a good first step.

Answer (score 2):

Well, [Peter Turner said it all really](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/25477/do-people-actually-make-invent-anything?noredirect=1#comment61084_25477):

> [T]he Calvinist perspective on free will probably has a lot to do with this. If you believe that man has a role to play in the creation of faith in others, you'll find man to be a co-creator (working with the Holy Spirit). If you believe God just put it there to begin with, then man is just a passive instrument and not a creator.

To put this into site guidelines I suggest asking for an Arminian or Calvinist perspective. I would ask how it is that Arminianism can explain the antinomy of God having given the creativity, deserves glory for that and all you create with it, yet *you* created with it, not God.